# How to replace the decimal comma to a point in <input type="number">?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

This does not work:

```
<input id="input" type="number" value = "10.5">
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.value = input.value.replace(/,/, ".");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ky6h0tpf/3/

Comment: `"10.5"` doesn't contain comma

Comment: Yes, but I see a comma.

Comment: You __see__ a comma, this is due to the locale settings of your machine/browser. If you'd log the value to the console, there will be a point. You can use the value (after converting to a number) in calculations as it is, no need to change it.   (I can see a comma too, since my locale settings use comma as a decimal separator.)

Comment: BTW: 1st param of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) isn't required to be `Regexp`, it may be a `String` as well: `input.value.replace(",", ".")`

Answer (score 0):

This answer will display a decimal and not a comma.

https://jsfiddle.net/ky6h0tpf/10/

```
<input id="input" type="number" value = "10.5">
```

It could be a problem with your browser locale.

Comment: Your fiddle shows me `10,5`. Though a bit confusing, this actually is not a problem at all.